# PHP get more after last limit

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make a simple "load more" button where I have an ajax request a load more page which loads a few more database entries. My problem is I can do my select statement like so:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT uid,username,image FROM tbl_multimedia LIMIT 3");
```

But every time I click it, I see the first 3 results, not the fourth and so forth. This code does not count or check to see which id has been loaded last and start from the next. I am trying to keep it simple, any quick ideas on what I can add here to make it count. I have the javascript part ready and working with AJAX, I am just stuck here.

My code is below:

```
try 
{
    // Query multimedia table
    $result = $db->query("SELECT uid,username,image FROM tbl_multimedia LIMIT 3");

    // Convert the object to a string
    $result->unescape(array(
        'username'      => 'string',
        'image' => 'string',
        'uid' => 'integer'
    ));

    // No users in our app :(
    $result->tossIfNoRows();
    ?>

    <?
    // Magic happens -> Create rows with every name found in the database
    foreach ($result as $row) 
    {
        ?>
        <div class="g_holder">
        <? echo '<a href="profile.php?user_id='.$row['uid'].'" ><img src="img/'.$row['image'].'" width="120" height="120"/></a>'; ?>
        <div class="g_caption">
            <p class="g_txt">
                <? echo $row['username']; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?
    }

} 
catch (fNoRowsException $e) 
{
    ?>
    <p>noone cares about using my app!</p>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: @diskrim: Put more effort to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an offset. So your query should be like so:

```
"SELECT uid,username,image FROM tbl_multimedia LIMIT {$offset},3"
```

Where offset is a number that increase by 3 after each click.

So the first time your page load it will be `0`, after the first click `$offset = 3`, and the next `$offset = 6` , and so on.

Comment: @diskrim you should note that this is way harder in just about every other db

Answer (score 0):

"With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):"

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have 10 entries loaded and want to load 3 additional entries, try `LIMIT 11,13` and you get 3 entries after the tenth.

Answer (score 0):

try using OFFSET. See [MYSQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT uid,username,image FROM tbl_multimedia LIMIT 3 OFFSET {$offset}");
```